# How can I call functions in different orders in PHP?

Tags: php

I am making a way to organize user into groups and need a way to check them. For example I have a method to check gender, which return true if there is no gender imbalance and false if there is. I also have similar methods to check age distribution and to check genders. For each of these methods I have a method which makes an optimized array of groups.

I.e. i have a method which optimizes groups based on gender. I would only call one of these methods if the respective check returns false. The problem I am running into is that when I optimize the groups based on a specific criterion i.e. gender, there is a chance that the new optimized groups have messed up another check criterion.

For example, if I check age, gender and skill level (my third check) and I find that there is an imbalance in age, proceed to optimize the groups with respect to age, then I could potentially mess up gender or skill level distributions. My solution to this problem was that If I could find a way call all variations of the check methods and break if a check all method returned true (all checks return true, all groups have good balances of age, gender and skill level).

Ex: 
Let A, B and C be check methods and optimize_A, optimize_B, optimize_C be the make optimized group methods. I need some way loop through the check methods 3! times (because there are 3 check methods and I need to run ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA). OR I could do a while loop and break if the method check all () returns true (all checks return true, all have good distributions) and break once I have run the all the combinations of the check methods.

Could anyone help me with this problem? Please bear in mind I am a novice programmer and have never done anything like this before. Thanks

**Edit**:

How could I do something like this JavaScript code snippet in php?

```
var arr = [check1, check2, check3],
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length),
    func = arr[rand];
func();
```

Here is my attempt:

```
<?php

$checks_to_run = array('check_gender','check_age','check_skill_level');
$rand = floor(rand(0, count($checks_to_run) - 1));
$func = $checks_to_run[$rand];
echo $this->.$func.($tmp); // $tmp is an array of groups 

?>
```

Comment: You're basically doing an N-way [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). there is no easy solution.

Comment: The best part about programming is actually trying something to see if it works, and that you can do it. If you get stuck on a particular section, then ask for help. You have the logic in front of you. Try something new!

Comment: `call_user_func(array($this,$func),$tmp);`, I don't know why this is `[on hold]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *almost had it*, just remove the dots at the end.

```
$checks_to_run = array('check_gender','check_age','check_skill_level');
$rand = floor(rand(0, count($checks_to_run) - 1));
$func = $checks_to_run[$rand];
echo $this->$func($tmp); // $tmp is an array of groups
```